# Create a proxy server changin the referer

Tags: node.js, cross-domain

I'm working on iis, now i need to redirect all request to an S3, it grants the access through the referer. But in my proxy server does not appear a referer only appears Host as the proxy (Host: proxy.domainhost.com).

i'm using request in nodejs, to do that

```
const app = require('express')();
const cors = require('cors');
const parser = require('body-parser');
const request = require('request');

app.use(cors());
app.use(parser.urlencoded({ extended: false }))
app.use(parser.json())
app.get('/api/*', function Server(req, res) {
  const url = "https://"+(req.url || '').slice(5)
  req.pipe(request(url)).pipe(res);
});
app.listen(process.env.PORT);
```

\ GET
proxy.domainhost.com/api/s3link/img/0001.png

There is another/better way? Those request are made by desktop app. And i need center them all to grant access to the s3.

Comment: https://github.com/request/request#custom-http-headers

Comment: That was really usefully

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
app.get('/api/*', function Server(req, res) {
  const url = "https://"+(req.url || '').slice(5)
  req.pipe(
    request({
      url,
      headers: {
        referer: "targetReferer"
      }
    })
  ).pipe(res);
});
app.listen(process.env.PORT);
```

Thanks for the comment, that's the answer.